# I cant access the value of dojo datetimepicker tag in java script

Tags: dojo, struts2

I am using the following date timepicker of dojo framework on my jsp, i am successfully accessing this value in my action class through beans.

```
<sx:datetimepicker id="smon" name="start_mon"
    toggleDuration="500" toggleType="explode" value="%{'today'}"
        displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        cssStyle="margin-top : 15px;
        margin-left: 23px;margin-right: 80px;">
</sx:datetimepicker>
```

and i want to access its value in java script as follows

```
var end_mon=document.form1.start_mon.value;
```

but its giving runtime error on the above line where i am accessing the date value. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, we can access its value in java script as follows. .

```
var startMonth=dojo.widget.byId("smon").getValue();
```

we can access its value by its id, in this case which is `"smon"`.